# How dns servers work know the ip address of website?

Tags: url, networking, dns, ip

My question is that suppose my website is "xyz.com"
I can access it anywhere in the world, but I'm curious to know how does all the dns servers know the ip address of my website..?
  I'm little bit confused..

Answer (score 5):

The main process that resolves an IP Address through DNS is referrals. A DNS Server will go through a process to find the Authorative Nameserver for your domain. The Authorative Nameserver is the server that is configured to answer queries for that domain. i.e. the godaddy DNS Servers, if you have purchased, and configured a domain name through them.

If you go to `www.example.com` from your PC, it will send a query to your configured DNS server, asking for `www.example.com`

If your configured DNS Server knows that answer already, i.e. it has been asked the same question recently, it will return the answer from cache (as long as it hasn't expired)

If your configured DNS Server doesn't know, then it will find out. In order to find out what server knows the answer, it needs to look up the name server for example.com first.

So the first query the nameserver makes is to the root domain "." (All DNS Servers *should* have these configured) to find out the nameservers for the `.com` domain.

When it has an address for the `.com` domain's nameservers, it will send a query asking for the nameserver for `example.com`

when it has the address for `example.com`'s nameservers, it will send the original query, for `www.example.com`, to that server, and return the answer to you (and put a copy in its cache incase anyone else asks)

Note: If you were looking for `www.test.example.com` then it would have asked example.com for the nameservers for `test.example.com` instead.

Answer (score 1):

[image: DNS resolution process]

- URL resolution in DNS happens from right to left.
- DNS comprises of Root Servers, Top Level Domain(TLD) and Authoritative Servers

For the example  www.example.com :

- Root Server queries the TLD for '.com' extension
- TLD searches the DNS cache for the domain, if not it queries the corresponding authoritative server for the domain 'example.com' to finally get the IP address for the host www.example.com, then return that IP address to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

That's why there are *DNS Root Servers*.

> At the top of the DNS system are DNS root servers. There are
>   approximately 500 root servers distributed around the planet,
>   addressed via 13 IP addresses. These root servers are the only ones
>   that contain the entire list of all domain names and IP addresses. So
>   eventually, a DNS request might make it all the way to the DNS root
>   servers if no other DNS server has the answer. If there is still no
>   answer at the root level, then the DNS request fails, and your browser
>   returns an error. [Source](https://internet.com/domains/what-is-a-dns-server/)